# Pelican theme CSS file is not copied to output

Tags: python, pelican

I'm running pelican locally on my ubuntu machine, inside a venv as suggested in the docs. I'm using the following command to run it.

```
pelican content/ -s pelicanconf.py -t themes/simple/ --autoreload --listen
```

When I make changes to .html templates, these are then shown in the output. However, if I change the .css file(s), the changes are not shown in the output and the CSS file in output/theme/css still has yesterday's timestamp on it, even tho I updated it a few seconds ago.

Things I've noticed:

- A change to the CSS file is apparently detected by the autoreload/listen part of pelican as it spots the change and re-processes, but the CSS changes are not copied.
- If I press Ctrl+C and re-run the command, the same thing happens.
- Deleting the output folder ***doesn't fix this*** - it seems the old CSS is being cached somewhere and copied into the output folder again?
- The best workaround I can think of is to manually copy the CSS file across to the output folder, but surely this should be built in?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably happening on the browser.

After re-building the `output` folder, don't forget to "hard" refresh the page, usually with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>